# Reshape data table

Tags: r, data.table, reshape2

I have a data table like (data is not necessarily ordered by 'col1')

```
    col0    col1      col2
1:  abc       1         a
2:  abc       2         b 
3:  abc       3         c 
4:  abc       4         d 
5:  abc       5         e
6:  def       1         a
7:  def       2         b 
8:  def       3         c 
9:  def       4         d 
10: def       5         e
```

I want to reshape it the following way

```
    col0      col1      col2      new_1   new_2   new_3   new_4
1:  abc         1         a         NA      NA       NA      NA
2:  abc         2         b         a       NA       NA      NA
3:  abc         3         c         b       a        NA      NA
4:  abc         4         d         c       b        a       NA 
5:  abc         5         e         d       c        b       a
6:  def         1         a         NA      NA       NA      NA
7:  def         2         b         a       NA       NA      NA
8:  def         3         c         b       a        NA      NA
9:  def         4         d         c       b        a       NA 
10: def         5         e         d       c        b       a
```

Basically I want to get previously occurred values of col2 for each row in the same row as above and if there is none the corresponding new column should say NA.

I can of course do it by merge on col2 5 times but I need to do this on a large table (in that case I will have to merge 20-30 times).

What is the best way to achieve it in R in 1 or 2 lines?

Comment: Can anyone provide a different solution without using developer version of data.table? Only using CRAN version! I

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `shift` from the devel version of data.table i.e. `v1.9.5` (Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).  By default, the `type` in `shift` is `lag`.  We can specify `n` as a vector, in this case `1:4`.  We assign (`:=`) the output to new columns.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
DT[, paste('new', 1:4, sep="_") := shift(col2, 1:4)]
DT
#   col1 col2 new_1 new_2 new_3 new_4
#1:    1    a    NA    NA    NA    NA
#2:    2    b     a    NA    NA    NA
#3:    3    c     b     a    NA    NA
#4:    4    d     c     b     a    NA
#5:    5    e     d     c     b     a
```

For the new dataset 'DT2', we need to group by 'col0' and then do the `shift` on 'col2'

```
DT2[, paste('new', 1:4, sep="_") := shift(col2, 1:4), by = col0]
DT2
#   col0 col1 col2 new_1 new_2 new_3 new_4
# 1:  abc    1    a    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 2:  abc    2    b     a    NA    NA    NA
# 3:  abc    3    c     b     a    NA    NA
# 4:  abc    4    d     c     b     a    NA
# 5:  abc    5    e     d     c     b     a
# 6:  def    1    a    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 7:  def    2    b     a    NA    NA    NA
# 8:  def    3    c     b     a    NA    NA
# 9:  def    4    d     c     b     a    NA
#10:  def    5    e     d     c     b     a
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = 1:5, col2 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 
new_1 = c(NA, "a", "b", "c", "d"), new_2 = c(NA, NA, "a", 
"b", "c"), new_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, "a", "b"), new_4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "a")), .Names = c("col1", "col2", "new_1", "new_2", 
"new_3", "new_4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))

DT <- as.data.table(df1)

df2 <- structure(list(col0 = c("abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", 
"def", 
"def", "def", "def", "def"), col1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), col2 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", 
 "c", "d", "e")), .Names = c("col0", "col1", "col2"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
DT2 <- as.data.table(df2)
```

Comment: I can't shift it because first the data is not necessarily ordered and I have this data for different categories. So, on shifting I may end up getting a value of some other category.

Comment: @user3664020  I am not sure what you meant by `can't shift`.  My code is based on the example you provided.

Comment: made some edits in the question. Can you please modify your answer based on the new data?

Comment: so I want to do what you just have done but for each category of 'col0' without running for loop or going the brute force way.

Comment: @user3664020  I updated the post.  Check if that helps

Comment: ok, this helped. What if I have to shift up instead of downwards?

Comment: @user3664020  Use `shift(col2, 1:4, type='lead')`

Comment: do you have any solution using only CRAN version of data.table not dev version?

Comment: @user3664020  I can't test now as I have installed the devel version.

Answer (score 0):

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(col0 = rep(c("abc", "def"), each=5), col1 = rep(1:5, 2), col2 = rep(letters[1:5],2))
```

**Procedure**

```
m <- matrix(ncol=max(df[,2]), nrow=dim(df)[1])
#defining a matrix of final shaped dimensions 

for (i in 1:10) {
    m[i,1:df[i,2]] <- (c(df[i:(i-df[i,2]+1),3]))
}
#replacements

df2 <- cbind(df, m)
#final combination

colnames(df2)[4:ncol(df2)] <- paste("new_", 1:ncol(m))
#column's renaming
```

**OUTPUTS**

```
> df
   col0 col1 col2
1   abc    1    a
2   abc    2    b
3   abc    3    c
4   abc    4    d
5   abc    5    e
6   def    1    a
7   def    2    b
8   def    3    c
9   def    4    d
10  def    5    e
> df2
   col0 col1 col2 new_ 1 new_ 2 new_ 3 new_ 4 new_ 5
1   abc    1    a      a   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
2   abc    2    b      b      a   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
3   abc    3    c      c      b      a   <NA>   <NA>
4   abc    4    d      d      c      b      a   <NA>
5   abc    5    e      e      d      c      b      a
6   def    1    a      a   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
7   def    2    b      b      a   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
8   def    3    c      c      b      a   <NA>   <NA>
9   def    4    d      d      c      b      a   <NA>
10  def    5    e      e      d      c      b      a
```